# How does one generate challenging different puzzles like the one in AirLock android game

Tags: android, game-development, artificial-intelligence, puzzles

here's the link of the app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iatll.airlock

I had studied AI in the final year of b.tech cs programme,   and i do remember some algorithm of generating and solving the 8 puzzle game; we had to implement it in Prolog (tough times)

But I'm not sure if the above mentioned app uses that same algorithm. Where do I need to look to create a puzzle game like that? They seriously couldn't have designed each level by hand right?  Had to be computer generated. How can I so that?

pardon me for not formatting,  I'm on a mobile device.

Comment: This is much better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: i found this in the faq -               'conceptual questions about software development.'

'algorithm and data structure concepts'
why then a downvote

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the levels of this game *really were* designed by hand, using the old but still very relevant art of **Level Design**.  In fact, generating these levels programmatically would have been too risky, as they would not necessarily produce the player experience that the developers wanted.

In general, though, the answer to these kind of questions of where to find such types of algorithms is generally to **invent them yourself**.  Though they might draw inspiration and pieces from other common algorithms, the end result is custom.  In the event that someone did produce a level generator for this game, it is likely that they manually determined the patterns and mechanics of how to do so - thus, either way, manual understanding of the generation of the levels is necessary.